# How do I get the photo I clicked using raspberry pi camera sent to my android app continuously

Tags: android, android-studio, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to send a photo clicked by the raspberry pi camera module to my android app over the internet. Also, this process should be continuous and automatic such that when a new picture is clicked it should overwrite the older one and the app automatically displays the new picture and this should work continuously until the raspberry pi camera is taking pictures.

Please can someone help me with this as I am new to using raspberry pi?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes we will help you to make your code continous. Please post the code for one picture.

Comment: That is too much. Why do you want both? If you have the first then you could yourself extend it to the second.

Comment: You will not get code here. This side is for helping people with their code. Probably you can find all the code you need on stackoverflow. I'm pretty shure even. But you have to find it yourself. And if you thank in advance you mostly will get no help as that is not what we want.

Comment: Not the code but even if someone can tell me how to go about this problem I can figure out the code. I just need help with the solution to the problem.